# Using a secondary membership provider in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am going to use the default built in membership provider in my app.  If the first provider does not validate the user then I want to try to validate the user against another provider.

I have my secondary provider set up in my web.config like this:

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <add name="SecondaryMemberShipProvider"
         type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider,System.Web, Version 4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
         enableSearchMethods="true"
         connectionUserName="MyDoman\user"
         connectionPassword ="password" 
         connectionStringName ="ADConnectionString" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

I added a class "SecondaryMemberShipProvider" that inherits from MembershipProvider.  I am unsure of how I code the ValidateUser method on my new class.

Comment: Wow.  It was as simple as putting this in the membership class.


       public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
        {
       return Membership.Providers["SecondaryMemberShipProvider"].ValidateUser(username, password);
        }